# jQuery-ui autocomplete in codeigniter not work

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui

I use jQuery-ui autocomplete in my codeigniter project. But the source value dose not  work!
Here is my code. Can you help me? 
Thanks a lot

my js file:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: "basic_controller/livesearch"
  });
});
```

my `controller`:

```
class Basic_controller extends CI_Controller {
   function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
   } //end constructor
   public function livesearch()
   {
    $search = 'a';
    $query = $this->turn_model->livesearch($search);
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
      $row_set[] =               
         htmlentities(stripslashes($row['firstName'].''.$row['lastName']));   
     }//end foreach

    }//end if
    echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
   }//end of livesearch method
}//end of class
```

and my model

```
class Turn_model extends CI_Model{
 function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();    
 }
 public function livesearch($search)
 {
    $this->db->like("firstName",$search);
    $this->db->or_like("lastName",$search);
    $query = $this->db->get("user_table");
    return $query ;
 }
}
```

Comment: looks like you're always searching for 'a' so I can see why nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Change your echo to return. I don't know if that will make a difference but the api expects it to be returned, that would be the first thing I tried.